# Python timeit problem

Tags: python, timeit

I'm trying to use the timeit module but I don't know how.
I have a main:

```
from Foo import Foo
if __name__ == '__main__':
...
   foo = Foo(arg1, arg2) 
   t = Timer("foo.runAlgorithm()")
   print t.timeit(2)
```

and my Class Foo has a method named as runAlgorithm()

the error is this:

> NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?
Can I take the time from a class method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using the necessary [`setup` parameter](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) for setting up the timeit environment, you can simply pass the method (or anything that is callable):

```
t = Timer(foo.runAlgorithm)
```

From the documentation:

> Changed in version 2.6: The stmt and setup parameters can now also take objects that are callable without arguments.

If you need to pass some arguments, you can use function currying with [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial), for example:

```
class C:
    def printargs(self, a, b):
        print a, b

from functools import partial
foo = C()
t = Timer(partial(foo.printargs, 1, 2))
```

Comment: I think *without arguments* needs to be highlighted

Comment: Well, if you need to pass arguments, you could simply use a small wrapper function.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Edited to include an example *with* arguments.

Answer (score 2):

as [docs example](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) show you need to pass `setup` statements:

```
t = Timer("foo.runAlgorithm()", 'from __main__ import foo')
```